# Apply different layouts to the site for different window size?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I know we can use media query to change the css for different sizes.

My question is: is it possible to change to a totally new page layout (or View in MVC) when window size, say when width < 500? Assume the controller is the same.

Kind of like: get the window size in the view, then decide what layout to use.

I know this is not a good way, but is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, by detecting screen size by js code and load the suitable content

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```